What to do with a wide text in appendix of a paper
I am writing a paper and want to include my Mathematica commands in an appendix. By exporting my commands as a .tex file and including it in my paper’s tex file, I end at a text too wide to be fitted to the resulting pdf (I receive a huge horizontal overfull warning). I prefer not to change anything by hand. What is the best (usual) solution?

Consider putting it in the supplementary material that can be downloaded. Perhaps even as a native Mathematica file. See journal instructions.

Thanks Jon. That is also a good choice. But actually I prefer to include it in an appendix.

LaTeX lets you extend the margins.

The right place for questions about TeX is https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Agree, this is better suited for TeX.SE. We could migrate it, but I'm not sure this meets their quality standards, as it is not described in enough detail to be reproducible. Consider adding a minimal working example, reviewing their guidelines and then making a new post over there.

I am not sure about my information, but I, for a very long time, believe that an appendix of a paper can be formatted in the landscape mode. Or is this not available in all places?

While it does involve changing your code by hand, in similar situations I've edited my code to break lines with the line continuation character before a new line, which tells the interpreter to keep reading the next line as if it were a continuation of the previous. That way, you will have code that executes as desired if copied to input, and also prettyprints as needed.
In Mathematica, if I remember right, the line continuation character is \, so something like
expr = 
  Function[x, x^2 + \
  Sin[x] + Log[x]];

